# How to allow free unencoded html in XmlNode or XmlElement using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, html, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm looking for a way to create an xml element that will accept a string of text that might contain html element (or any other valid xml element) which might look like this:

```
"Test text with <strong>custom nodes</strong> that shouldn't be encoded"
```

I've tried using `XmlAnyElement` combined with `XmlNode[]` but with no luck.

The output I want should look like:

```
<Root>
    <Text>
        Test text with <strong>custom nodes</strong> that shouldn't be encoded
    </Text>
</Root>
```

For this class:

```
public class Root
{
    // Problematic property
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

What's the simpliest way to achieve such behavior (part of the problem is that my element might start and/or end with bare text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple workaround I found was creating an `XmlElement` helper property that will return the string wrapped with `<Text>..</Text>` as an `XmlElement` using `XmlDocument` and ignoring the `Text` property like this:

```
public class Root
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlElement TextElement
    {
        get
        {
            var x = new XmlDocument();
            x.LoadXml(string.Format("<Text>{0}</Text>", Text));
            return x.DocumentElement;
        }
        set { Text = value.InnerXml; }
    }
}
```

This will accept **anything** under `Text` but notice that if the `Text` property will be set with invalid xml, the serialization will fail.